# How to break out of .each() by index number

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to break out each three items in a list and add a class to that child like;

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li><!--target list item-->
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li><!--target list item-->
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the nth-child pseudo selector

```
$("ul li:nth-child(3n)").addClass("break-here");
```

Comment: Nice.  I would have looped, so you just taught me something.

Comment: I think that doesn't works in IE <= 8 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @luso; jQuery's selector syntax may look like CSS, but is in fact implemented in code. jQuery selectors should work regardless of browser support for CSS selectors.

Comment: great, I really didn't know... thanks! @Alnitak I would NEVER let IE stand anywhere :D Anyways, couple of answers in the classic way are already posted.

Comment: @luso all those other answers will break if there's more than one `<ul>` on the page.

Answer (score 5):

There's a CSS pseudo selector for that:

```
:nth-child(xn+y)
```

selects every `x` child starting at `y`, so in your case `x = 3` and `y = 1` (the default)

```
$('li:nth-child(3n)').addClass(...);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8WDK4/

See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo and [examples](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li><!--target list item-->
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li><!--target list item-->
    <li>7</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
i = 0;
$.each($("li"), function(key,value) {
    i++;
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        //Do things
    }

})
</script>
```

Comment: not withstanding the loop being unncessary, you should have used `$('li').each(...)`, not `$.each($('li'), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li")​.each(function(index,item){
    console.debug(index)
    if(index % 3 == false){
        $(this).addClass("newClass");
    }
})​
```

This will to the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/TYuAn/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with no pseudo selectors

```
collection.each(function(i, item){
    if(! i%3) {
        $(item).addClass('c');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').each(function(i,e){
  $(e).eq((i+1)%3).addClass('red');
});
```

### *[demo jsbin](http://jsbin.com/isoxim/edit#javascript,html,live)*